# Knockout bound select dropdown with default text and two way value binding

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, knockout.js

I have a select control bound to a Typescript viewmodel, the select has a default option ("Select...") that should be displayed on page load. If the viewmodel is passed an initial period, this should then override the default as the selected option.

I can pass an initial period to the model and via the callback use that on the parent model to save an entry on the form. However, the value binding fails to work with the control and the "Select..." text remains displayed in the control as opposed to the initial period label being the selected option.

View

```
<div id="customPeriodSelection" data-bind="with: customPeriodSelection">
<select id="periodSelect" class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedOption, event: { change: onChange }">
    <option>@Labels.SelectDD</option>
    <!--ko foreach: {data: customGroups}-->
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: { label: label}">
        <!--ko foreach: {data: customPeriods}-->
        <option data-bind="text: $data.label, value: $data"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </optgroup>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

Typescript

```
export class CustomPeriod {
    constructor(
        public start: Iso8601DateString,
        public end: Iso8601DateString,
        public label: string) { }

    identifier = () => {
        return this.start + "-" + this.end;
    }

    static mapCustomPeriod = (period: any) => {
        return new CustomPeriod(
            period.startDate,
            period.endDate,
            period.label
        )
    }
}

export class CustomPeriodSelection {
    customFrequencyId: number;
    customPeriods: KnockoutObservableArray<CustomPeriod> = ko.observableArray([]);
    selectedOption: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable();

    constructor(
        customFrequencyId: number,
        initialPeriod: any,
        public callback: (customPeriod: CustomPeriod) => void
    ) {
        var base = this;
        this.customFrequencyId = customFrequencyId;

        Verco.Services.GetData("GetPeriods", {
            frequency: customFrequencyId
        },
            function (result: any[]) {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    _.each(result, function (customPeriod: any) {
                        base.customPeriods.push(CustomPeriod.mapCustomPeriod(customPeriod));
                    })
                }
            });

        if (initialPeriod !== null) {
            var mappedPeriod = CustomPeriod.mapCustomPeriod(initialPeriod);
            this.selectedOption(mappedPeriod);
            this.callback(this.selectedOption());
        }
    }

    customGroups: KnockoutComputed<any[]> = ko.computed(() => {

        var groupedList = _.groupBy(this.customPeriods(), function (customPeriod: CustomPeriod) {
            return Verco.Format.FormatDate(customPeriod.end, DateFormats.Year);
        });

        return _.map(groupedList, function (customPeriod: any) {
            return {
                label: Verco.Format.FormatDate(customPeriod[0].end, DateFormats.Year),
                customPeriods: customPeriod
            }
        });
    });

    onChange = () => {
        if (this.callback !== null) {
            this.callback(this.selectedOption());
        }
    };
}
```

The initialPeriod passed in

```
{customFrequencyId: 1008, startDate: "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z", endDate: "2017-01-28T00:00:00Z", label: "P1 2017"}
```

Mapped to...

```
CustomPeriod {start: "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z", end: "2017-01-28T00:00:00Z", label: "P1 2017"}
```

So my question is.. How when passing in a period, mapping it to the type above and assigning it to the "selectedOption" observable, do I make the control display the correct selection? Do all of the individual properties on the CustomPeriod need to be observable?

I've had a look at [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/aCS7D/) from Ryan Niemeyer as he manipulates the Options as observables, do I need to replace the Computed with a similar way of building the overarching array? I've tried, but without success..

Comment: Without digging in to your code too much... Why are you using a `change` event handler? The `value` binding already takes care of this...

Comment: The change event is used with the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is that the default value you're trying to select isn't in the list of available options. Every time you call mapCustomPeriod you're creating a new object. Even if that object's contents are identical to the contents of one in your list the objects themselves are two completely different object instances and are not equivalent.

Try setting your default after the options list has been populated, and setting it by looping through the existing options to find the one that matches whatever criteria you want to use to define "equal".

```
Verco.Services.GetData("GetPeriods", {
        frequency: customFrequencyId
    },
        function (result: any[]) {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                _.each(result, function (customPeriod: any) {
                    base.customPeriods.push(CustomPeriod.mapCustomPeriod(customPeriod));
                });
                base.setValueByLabel(initialPeriod.label); //set default via label
            }
        });
...

this.setValueByLabel = function(label){
    for(var i=0; i<base.customGroups().length; i++){
        var group = base.customGroups()[i];
        for(var j=0; j<group.customPeriods.length; j++){
            var item = group.customPeriods[j];
          if(item.label === label){
                base.selectedOption(item);
              return;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling an empty state should be as simple as setting the `optionsCaption` on the options binding.

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountry,
        >>-------> optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: I'm unable to use the OptionsCaption in conjunction with the foreach looping on the select control. The issue is not the displaying of an empty state, it is updating the select list to show a selected item as an initial valuer, if one is set. If one isn't set, the empty value is displayed.